# Como fazer uma codition dentro de um NOT IN no SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suponhamos que eu tenha os seguintes dados, matriculas, categoria, e situação:

```
1- 1 - Encerrado
2- 10 - Concluído
3- 11 - Pendente
5 - 2 - Encerrado
6 - 1 - Pendente
9- 10- Encerrado
```

E eu quero fazer um select que me apresente os resultados  retirando as matriculas 5,6,7. Mas, se o registro for igual a Encerrado, dessas matriculas 5,6,7, deve ser apresentado.

Ou seja, o resultado final deve apresentar as matriculas 1,2,3,5 e 9.

Como fazer?

Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

> ```
> WHERE t.categoriaId IN (1,2,10,11)
> AND (t. matricula NOT IN ( 5,6,9 ) AND situacao 'Encerrado')
> ```

Mas ele me retira todos os cadastros que estão diferente de encerrados, não apenas dentro do conjunto 5,6,9.

Como fazer?

Comment: Paulo, nesse caso você não deveria utilizar AND e sim o OR, já tentou dessa forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Você deve substituir o primeiro AND pelo OR, como mencionado abaixo:

```
     WHERE t.categoriaId IN (1,2,10,11)
     OR (t. matricula NOT IN ( 5,6,9 ) AND situacao 'Encerrado')
```

Abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Pela sua explicação eu deduzo você quer retirar as matrículas 5,6,7 isto é:

```
t. matricula NOT IN (5, 6, 7)
```

mas se a situação for 'Encerrado' então considerar, independente da matrícula, então use:

```
t. matricula NOT IN (5, 6, 7) OR situacao = 'Encerrado'
```